# Cuda Kernel Code doesn't cover all the image

Tags: opencv, image-processing, cuda, gpu

I'm trying to equalize a histogram by writing cuda kernel code. The main problem is that the operation seems correct up to a certain line of the image, after which the output is wrong, but I can't understand why, below is the code and images.

Expected output:

[image: Expected output]

Output obtained:

[image: Output obtained]

I can't understand why, I have already checked that the histogram contains the exact values, in fact the expected output is obtained by performing the operation on the CPU and I have no problems, as soon as I pass the "Output Obtained" image to the GPU is the result. Now I show the code

## **Cuda Kernel Code**

```
__global__ void equalizeHistCUDA(unsigned char* input, unsigned char* output, int *cumulative_hist, int cols, int rows) {
    int nGrayLevels = 256, area = cols*rows;
    int i = blockIdx.y * blockDim.y + threadIdx.y;
    int j = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    if (i < rows && j < cols){  
        int pixelValue = input[i * cols + j];
        output[i * cols + j] = static_cast<uchar>((static_cast<double>(nGrayLevels) / area) * cumulative_hist[pixelValue]);
    }
}
```

## **Part of the main**

```
nThreadPerBlocco = dim3(4, 3);
    numBlocks.y = gpu_resizedImage.rows / nThreadPerBlocco.y + ((gpu_resizedImage.rows % nThreadPerBlocco.y) == 0 ? 0 : 1);
    numBlocks.x = gpu_resizedImage.cols / nThreadPerBlocco.x + ((gpu_resizedImage.cols % nThreadPerBlocco.x) == 0 ? 0 : 1);
    cv::cuda::GpuMat gpu_equalizedImage(600,600,CV_8UC1);
equalizeHistCUDA<<<numBlocks,nThreadPerBlocco>>>(gpu_resizedImage.data,gpu_equalizedImage.data,cumHist_device,gpu_resizedImage.cols,gpu_resizedImage.rows);
    cudaDeviceSynchronize();
    cudaError_t cudaErr = cudaGetLastError();
    if (cudaErr != cudaSuccess)
        fprintf(stderr, "Errore CUDA: %s\n", cudaGetErrorString(cudaErr));

    cv::Mat img;
    gpu_equalizedImage.download(img);
    cv::imwrite("test.jpg",img);
```

I have already checked that all the structures I use are correctly filled. Any suggestions?

Comment: Your assumption about the layout of the image in memory is almost certainly wrong.

Comment: @talonmies is right (I haven't read through your code yet, there might be other problems too). GpuMat::isContinous() will tell you how the memory allocation happened, you should check its output (https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d0/d60/classcv_1_1cuda_1_1GpuMat.html#a400fc4c7880bf132f2ffea03892486b0)

Comment: @talonmies you guys are right because the output is false so the allocation is not contiguous, but how can I solve this problem?

Comment: EDIT: I found the cv::cuda::createContinuous() function, now I'll test it and post the answer.

Comment: New EDIT: ` cv::cuda::createContinuous()` is the solution of my problem. @talonmies and @user2986898 thank you!
Last question: How can I write a complete answer and mark it as correct in order to help those who enter this post?

Comment: You will have to be more specific. In general you should be able to answer your own question like any other. See [Can I answer my own question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)

Comment: @paleonix it's what I want, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently OpenCV x CUDA does not allocate images on gpu contiguously so my CUDA kernel code computed addresses in linear memory, but this was not useful since OpenCV does not store as it stores on cpu.
The solution is to use this to allocate the memory on the GPU:

```
gpu_equalizedImageSM = cv::cuda::createContinuous(gpu_resizedImage.rows,
                           gpu_resizedImage.cols,
                           CV_8UC1);
```

Having done this it is possible to access as I did in the kernel.